# How to format content in html textarea as xml on the fly

Tags: html, formatting

I have a page that users are able to add xml markup into a text area input. I'd like after they enter it that it be color-coded and formatted as xml would look in an IDE such as Visual Studio. Anybody know of a script or tool that would allow for this within a client-side browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [CodeMirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror), a syntax-highlighting editor in Javascript for browsers. [This](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/htmltest.html) is an example for XML editing.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **you can't**.

Not in an `TEXTAREA`, as the one here in SO.

The example in SO is very good, as it has a `TEXTAREA` where we type the text, and a `DIV` box below where you can see what you type formatted.

You could also go through the `contentEditable = "true"`, but it's a real pain to do it properly...

Answer (score 2):

A nice option would be this: [vkBeautify](http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkbeautify/)

Here is an example:

```js
(function() {

function createShiftArr(step) {

 var space = '    ';
 
 if ( isNaN(parseInt(step)) ) {  // argument is string
  space = step;
 } else { // argument is integer
  switch(step) {
   case 1: space = ' '; break;
   case 2: space = '  '; break;
   case 3: space = '   '; break;
   case 4: space = '    '; break;
   case 5: space = '     '; break;
   case 6: space = '      '; break;
   case 7: space = '       '; break;
   case 8: space = '        '; break;
   case 9: space = '         '; break;
   case 10: space = '          '; break;
   case 11: space = '           '; break;
   case 12: space = '            '; break;
  }
 }

 var shift = ['\n']; // array of shifts
 for(ix=0;ix<100;ix++){
  shift.push(shift[ix]+space); 
 }
 return shift;
}

function vkbeautify(){
 this.step = '    '; // 4 spaces
 this.shift = createShiftArr(this.step);
};

vkbeautify.prototype.xml = function(text,step) {

 var ar = text.replace(/>\s{0,}</g,"><")
     .replace(/</g,"~::~<")
     .replace(/\s*xmlns\:/g,"~::~xmlns:")
     .replace(/\s*xmlns\=/g,"~::~xmlns=")
     .split('~::~'),
  len = ar.length,
  inComment = false,
  deep = 0,
  str = '',
  ix = 0,
  shift = step ? createShiftArr(step) : this.shift;

  for(ix=0;ix<len;ix++) {
   // start comment or <![CDATA[...]]> or <!DOCTYPE //
   if(ar[ix].search(/<!/) > -1) { 
    str += shift[deep]+ar[ix];
    inComment = true; 
    // end comment  or <![CDATA[...]]> //
    if(ar[ix].search(/-->/) > -1 || ar[ix].search(/\]>/) > -1 || ar[ix].search(/!DOCTYPE/) > -1 ) { 
     inComment = false; 
    }
   } else 
   // end comment  or <![CDATA[...]]> //
   if(ar[ix].search(/-->/) > -1 || ar[ix].search(/\]>/) > -1) { 
    str += ar[ix];
    inComment = false; 
   } else 
   // <elm></elm> //
   if( /^<\w/.exec(ar[ix-1]) && /^<\/\w/.exec(ar[ix]) &&
    /^<[\w:\-\.\,]+/.exec(ar[ix-1]) == /^<\/[\w:\-\.\,]+/.exec(ar[ix])[0].replace('/','')) { 
    str += ar[ix];
    if(!inComment) deep--;
   } else
    // <elm> //
   if(ar[ix].search(/<\w/) > -1 && ar[ix].search(/<\//) == -1 && ar[ix].search(/\/>/) == -1 ) {
    str = !inComment ? str += shift[deep++]+ar[ix] : str += ar[ix];
   } else 
    // <elm>...</elm> //
   if(ar[ix].search(/<\w/) > -1 && ar[ix].search(/<\//) > -1) {
    str = !inComment ? str += shift[deep]+ar[ix] : str += ar[ix];
   } else 
   // </elm> //
   if(ar[ix].search(/<\//) > -1) { 
    str = !inComment ? str += shift[--deep]+ar[ix] : str += ar[ix];
   } else 
   // <elm/> //
   if(ar[ix].search(/\/>/) > -1 ) { 
    str = !inComment ? str += shift[deep]+ar[ix] : str += ar[ix];
   } else 
   // <? xml ... ?> //
   if(ar[ix].search(/<\?/) > -1) { 
    str += shift[deep]+ar[ix];
   } else 
   // xmlns //
   if( ar[ix].search(/xmlns\:/) > -1  || ar[ix].search(/xmlns\=/) > -1) { 
    str += shift[deep]+ar[ix];
   } 
   
   else {
    str += ar[ix];
   }
  }
  
 return  (str[0] == '\n') ? str.slice(1) : str;
}

window.vkbeautify = new vkbeautify();

})();

var xmlData = '<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don\'t forget me this weekend!</body></note>';
xmlData = vkbeautify.xml(xmlData);
$('textarea').val(xmlData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```